# Android wear os displays heart rate as 1 when trying it on the device

Tags: android, wear-os, heartrate

I've made a simple app for wear os that displays the heart  rate on a textView. The app runs perfectly with no bugs but when it comes to displaying the value it just says 1. The sensor works fine with other apps.

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements SensorEventListener{

private TextView mTextView;
private TextView mTextViewHeart;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mHeartRateSensor;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text);

    mTextViewHeart = findViewById(R.id.heart);

    // Enables Always-on
    setAmbientEnabled();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    assert mSensorManager != null;
    mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT);
}

public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float mHeartRateFloat = event.values[0];

    int mHeartRate = Math.round(mHeartRateFloat);

    mTextViewHeart.setText(Integer.toString(mHeartRate));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Comment: this is usually because Permission for hearrate needs to be requested and granted

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired sensor type?

> Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT

You could consider changing it to

> mHeartRateSensor =
> mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);